# Uploadify How to create a new folder and load files to it

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, uploadify

**can anyone tell how to pass the value from jquery to uploadify.php `dynfolder:$("#storeloyaltyid").val()`,//value is photo1 m not able to fetch in uploadify.php**

Jquery

```
if($("#uploadphotoz").length>0){

        uploadphotoz();

    }

    function uploadphotoz(){

        $('#uploadphotoz').Uploadify({

            uploader:urljs+"/jslib/Uploadify.swf",
            cancelImage:urljs+"/image/cancel.png",
            buttonImage:urljs+"/image/browse_button.png",
            uploadUrl:urljs+"/jslib/uploadify.php",
            dynfolder:$("#storeloyaltyid").val(),//value is photo1
            height  : 21,
            width   :59,
            auto    : true,
            fileLimit:1,
            preview:'stuimgpreview',
            onComplete: function(event,status,imgs){   
                $("#memPhoto").val(imgs);
            },
            onRemove:function(event,imgs){
                $("#memPhoto").val(imgs);
            }
        });
    }
```

uploadify.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $filetmpname = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES["Filedata"]["type"];
    $fileSizeMB = ($_FILES["Filedata"]["size"] / 1024 / 1024);

    // Place file on server, into the images folder
    //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "../uploaded_photos/".$filename);
    $dynfolder=$_POST['dynfolder'];
mkdir($dynfolder, 0755, true);move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "../uploaded_photos"."/".$dynfolder."/".$filename);.../uploaded_photos/photos1/1.jpg

}elseif($_POST['d']){
    $filename = $_POST['d'];
    $dynfolder=$_POST['dynfolder'];
mkdir($dynfolder, 0755, true);
$dFile=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "../uploaded_photos"."/".$dynfolder."/".$filename);//.../uploaded_photos/photos1/1.jpg
    unlink($dFile);

}
?>
```

I am not able to create a new folder called photos1 in uploaded_photos folder... the path should be `.../uploaded_photos/photos1/1.jpg`  ,`dynfolder:$("#storeloyaltyid").val(),//value is photo1` ,Can anyone tell what is the problem with the code.

Comment: Do you know where the directory is actually trying to be made? Try `mkdir('../uploaded_photos/'.$dynfolder, ...)`. I don't know if that will work, but if not, also try an absolute path: `mkdir('/path/to/uploaded_photos/'.$dynfolder, ...)`

Comment: @ChristianVarga ok.. willl try it and let u know

Comment: @ChristianVarga no its not creating !! its just uploading to the `uploaded_photos` folder

Comment: can u tell me how to pass the value from jquery to uploadify.php `dynfolder:$("#storeloyaltyid").val()`,//value is photo1 m not able to fetch in uploadify.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#uploadphotoz').Uploadify({
    ...
    'method': 'post',
    'formData': { 'dynfolder': $("#storeloyaltyid").val() },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You might have to change `/../`to `../`. I can't test this at the moment.

Also, you should check if the directory exists and if the fileupload is successful. I don't know what PHP does if the folder already is in place.

```
<?php
$basepath = dirname(__FILE__);

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $filetmpname = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES["Filedata"]["type"];
    $fileSizeMB = ($_FILES["Filedata"]["size"] / 1024 / 1024);
    $dynfolder = $_POST['dynfolder'];
    mkdir($basepath.'/../'.$_POST['dynfolder'], 0755, true);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $basepath.'/../'.$_POST['dynfolder'].'/'.$filename);
}
?>
```

EDIT:

The Javascript-problem is that you just "made up" a variable in the object called `dynfolder`. Uploadify has a setting called formData. Pass the variable here.

For example:

```
[...]
height : 21,
width : 59,
auto : true,
formData : jQuery.parseJSON('{"dynfolder":"'+$("#storeloyaltyid").val()+'"}'),
[...]
```

Comment: can u tell me how to pass the value from jquery to uploadify.php `dynfolder:$("#storeloyaltyid").val(),//value is photo1` m not able to fetch in uploadify.php

Comment: Fire up FireBug and check what values are sent from the script. Does the upload work? According to the documentation, it should work as expected.

Comment: its is working...but uploading to the uploaded_photos,but if i give dynfolder="somename"; in uploadify.php the directory is created and placed in it...so the problem is in the dynfolder value?